# Could all types of filling be used as macaron filling?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, macarons, filling

I've done a lot of research about French macarons recently and figured (every single recipe has a sentence describing macarons as finicky) the amount of ingredients for macaron shells cannot be changed. I'd have changed the amount of sugar used if I could, but then I prefer to get a beautiful macaron shell that is too sweet for my taste rather than a cracked one which tastes OK! So I decided to go for a filling that could milden the sweetness of macaron shells. The question is, do all types of filling work as a macaron filling? For instance, I have a recipe for cake filling (frosting) which calls for:

600 gr mascarpone or cream cheese

1 cup powdered sugar

1/2 cup cocoa powder

200 gr melted chocolate mixed together and fold in 2 cups whipped cream, which tastes awesome. Is it possible to use it as macaron filling? Does it hold in between macaron shells, could it be stored on the counter and etc.

Comment: It will be very difficult to know whether the final texture of this "filling" is suitable for macarons unless you tell us about the texture.... unless you post the exact recipe for us to try (or be familiar with already). Could you please add that to your post? My main concern would be the use of non-shelf-stable ingredients, particularly the whipped cream, would make them soften quickly, if not altogether soggy.

Comment: @catija I have the same concern, if that wouldn't work as a filling, what filling would be suitable? I'll edit my post to add the recipe, thanks.

Comment: I am not sure this question is objectively answerable...as, really, almost anything can work...it depends on what result you want.  For example, I make cocoa macaroon with a chicken liver pate filling that is savory and delicious.  As long as the filling is able to be piped and will not run out, it will work.  Maybe I am not understanding the question.

Comment: Yes. I always use a buttercream frosting though, as I know how to make that in my head, know how to flavor it, and it's stable. You can use jams, cream cheese frosting, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't make macarons often, and I really hate hunting around for fillings that work, so I use a very comprehensive list of ideas from [Sortrachen](http://www.sortrachen.com/20-macaron-shell-filling-recipes/). There are 20 recipes there, so it's not often I have to do a lot of searching. When I'm refreshing my mind as to the types of alternatives I could use, I head to [Indulge with Mimi](http://www.indulgewithmimi.com/macaron-filling-ideas/). As you can see if you check it out, it shows that just about anything can be used as a filling, but with different results for different occasions; for instance, one would never use a jelly filling in a macaron that is going to wait a full day before being served. Mimi does a great job of outlining the pros and cons of each type of filling, while Sortrachen delivers some awesome recipes.