# Dulce De leche as a macaron filling

Tags: macarons, dulce-de-leche

[as a follow up question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67729/could-all-types-of-filling-be-used-as-macaron-filling), I'd use dulce de leche (Slow Cooker Dulce De Leche) for the macaron filling, how do I milden its sweetness? Could I mix it with melted dark chocolate for example, and will it have the desired consistency? Google suggested Dulce de Leche buttercream for the right consistency but it is even sweeter than the Dulce De Leche itself and make the whole cookie cloying! Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use dulce de leche as a filling or topping as well, but you are right, it is a bit too sweet, so I tone it down... one way to make it milder is to incorporate some cream and a bit of melted dark chocolate, but you cannot just mix it in...

Leave the dulce de leche in the fridge overnight. Pour off any liquid that separates out. Mix in a bowl to smooth out any lumps. In a separate bowl, whip up some double cream (ratio 2:1:0,3, dulce de leche:cream:chocolate) to stiff peaks. Add cream to dulce de leche and beat until combined. Melt the dark chocolate and stir into mixture. Refrigerate for about 30mins so the melted chocolate in the mixture can stiffen up a bit.

It's delicious and not as sweet as pure dulce de leche at all!

Answer (score 0):

Some options that I would try:

- Use [toasted sugar](http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/05/how-to-make-caramel-without-melting-sugar.html) while making dulce de leche
- Substitute part of the sugar in dulce de leche with glucose, or another sugar less sweet than sucrose. This might help with the spreadability as well.
- Try [cajeta](http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/04/how-to-make-goats-milk-cajeta.html) instead of dulce de leche.

Answer (score 0):

Depending your "Dulce de leche" consistency i probably would mix it with chocolate, something close to 70/30 (dulce/chocolate). Bring the Dulce to 70 degre celsius and then incorporate chocolate chunks using a spatula only (we don't want air on it).